# Simplifying a class's method's multiple definitions

Tags: c++, coding-style

I have several methods of a class that are very similar to each other.  They vary only in the addition of other arguments to the method.  The base method has seven arguments.

Here's my current code:

```
void Noise::calcFBM(float* arr, int xsize, int ysize,
    int startOct, int endOct, double amp, double freq)
{
    //Calculate Fractal Brownian Motion
}

void Noise::calcFBM(float* arr, int xsize, int ysize,
    int startOct, int endOct, double amp, double freq,
    std::function<float (float)> modifier)
{
    //Calculate Fractal Brownian Motion
    //Apply modifier (lambda function taking (value)) to each point
}

void Noise::calcFBM(float* arr, int xsize, int ysize,
    int startOct, int endOct, double amp, double freq,
    std::function<float (float, float, float)> modifier)
{
    //Calculate Fractal Brownian Motion
    //Apply modifier (lambda function taking (value, xPos, yPos)) to each point
}
```

I want to add a variant for each of those which would add in either one structure or four floats (probably the structure, in order to reduce the number of arguments).

Should I simplify by using only the function with the **most** arguments, defaulting what I can, and forcing the programmer to set the rest?

Comment: Show us the code please

Comment: @Christophe It is rather large to post—a simplified version would be fine, right?

Comment: @Numeri absolutely.  Simplified is great!

Comment: Do the two last variants just transform the result of the very first function (i.e. mathematically speaking `calcFBM3 = calcFBM1 o modifier`) ?

Comment: @Christophe Yes. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use default arguments. Since the types of your `modifier` argument would be different, you would need to template it like this:

```
template <typename Func = std::function<float(float, float, float)> >
void calcFBM(float* arr, int xsize, int ysize,
    int startOct, int endOct, double amp, double freq,
    Func modifier = [](float x, float y, float z){return id;})
{
}
```

Please modify the default lambda to return whatever corresponds to the identity modifier function, i.e., the one equivalent to your first overload without a modifier.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!  I was wondering if templates were required, but frankly I haven't used them enough.  I'll accept your answer in a few minutes, as it fully meets my question, but of course I wouldn't like to discourage any further answers, in case there's an even better way.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Numeri Also, if you only have a small set of possible `Func`s that you care for, you could explicitly instantiate them. This allows you to keep the function definitions in the source file.

Comment: No, I'd prefer it to be left open to whatever modifiers a programmer would care to pass it.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't fully work as I would like it to.  This does not allow for the Func argument to be left off, nor does it allow the Func to be of type `std::function<float (float)>`.  I believe this is due to the line in the templated function using modifier: If I pass it three arguments (value, x, and y), three are needed, and it must exist. Any fixes for that?

Comment: @Numeri Ah yes, I see your point - this is an annoying situation indeed. One way would be to create a helper function that modifies `modifier` to ensure that it has the required arity. It will do this by simply adding dummy unused arguments, allowing you to always say `modified_modifier(x,y,z)` even when `modifier` was a `float(float)`. Is that good enough?

Comment: Yes, but at that point I think it might be just as easy to simply define it twice: once without `modifier`, and one with it (and all three arguments) and the added structure.  After that, I think it's just getting into bad/messy programming.  (If I'm not right about that being sort of an ugly coding style, please correct me—I'd just like to learn clear coding practices!) Thanks!

Comment: If it is the case that there's not a simple, neat answer (or that that is the simple, neat, answer), then just add whatever is necessary into the answer and I'll gladly accept it anyway.

Comment: It depends on how ugly you think templates look :) From an FP POV, this might look conceptually elegant but ugly implementation-wise. Will edit the answer and you decide.

Comment: How would one make a helper function?  I'm not quite sure how to distinguish between a lambda function of `float(float)` and one of `float(float, float, float)` in the helper function.

Comment: I'm sorry... I'm not sure where the `std::function` is in that code demo.  That looks like template overloading of an operator to me. :)

Comment: <Facepalm>. Didn't give you the permalink :) That was just the url to coliru. So it probably shows the code you were experimenting with last. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7abf6bc8a8a36d5) you go.

Comment: Thanks. I figured something like that had happened! :)

Comment: Um... My brain might have just broken trying to read that code... Can I have a synopsis of it, in English?  (Obviously I don't need a perfect in-depth understanding—but enough to avoid using just copy-paste code.)

Comment: Added an explanation [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a18477be2171016f).